# Set `required` for object type field in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

This one works fine:

```
{
  name: {
    first: { type: String, required: true },
    last: { type: String, required: true }
  }
}
```

But this one is not working

```
{
  name: {
    required: true,
    first: { type: String },
    last: { type: String }
  }
}
```

It won't even start:

> /Users/albertgao/codes/temp/aaa/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:751
>       throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}` is not ` +
>       ^
>
> TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `True` is not a valid type at path `name.required`.

How to say that I want `name` to be required without setting each of its sub-fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the field:TYPE shorthand, which shouldn't be mixed with option fields like required. Instead I think you can try to not use shorthands in the parent fields like this:

```
{
  name: {
    type: { 
       first: String,
       last: String
   },
   required: true
}
```

or even more explicit:

```
{
  name: {
    type: { 
       first: { type: String},
       last: { type: String}
   },
   required: true
}
```